# ASP.net MVC 4, Friendly url and chinese

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, friendly-url, chinese-locale, myprettycms

I used friend url jquery plug in (http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/friendurl/) to create my menu editor.
[image: My pretty cms menu editor (2 languages mode)]

My wife is chinese and I ask her to type chinese text to try if my menu works.

It's possible to type and save chinese chars but I realized I can't create chinese friendly url.

Could you tell me how Chinese web masters deal with **friendly url** and **chinese text** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transate any Unicode URL into an equivalent URL using basic ASCII characters with Punycode

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Punycode can be entered in the URL bar and will be resolved to the original Unicode URL.